# HTML 5 canvas fill color

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having a problem with the following script

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    img = new Image,
    url = 'http://i.imgur.com/1xweuKj.png',
    grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h);

grd.addColorStop(0, 'rgb(0, 130, 230)');
grd.addColorStop(1, 'rgb(0, 20, 100)');

img.onload = loop;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = url;

function loop(x) {
    /// since we will change composite mode and clip:
    ctx.save();

    /// clear background with black
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    /// remove waveform, change composite mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    /// fill new alpha, same mode, different region.
    /// as this will remove anything else we need to clip it
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.rect(0, 0, x, h);
    ctx.clip();    /// et clipping
    ctx.fill();    /// use the same rect to fill

    /// remove clip and use default composite mode
    ctx.restore();

    /// loop until end
}
```

When i do `loop(40)` this works and then if i do `loop(50)` then also it works but when i want to give smaller value(like `loop(20)`) than the current value it doesn't works.

Can anyone please let me know what is the problem here ?

it works for all increasing values but not for decreasing values.

[Check on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZx8v/3/)

Comment: works fine even with small values

Comment: It works but not at the same time. Suppose you did loop(60) then do loop(20) , it will show loop(60) value. I fixed it through `ctx.beginPath();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the workaround and it works fine now.

I achieved it through `ctx.beginPath();`